# how to find column as exception cause in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i have a table that the content of it:

```
ID    A        B
---    ---    ----
 1   123      &%df
 2   587      364
```

A function was written to find invalid number(below script)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_number RETURN number IS
  A_var     number(15);
  B_var     number(15);
  BEGIN

  for u in (select id, 
                   A,
                   B,
              from TABLE_NAME) LOOP
    BEGIN
      select 
             to_number(u.A),
             to_number(u.B),
             into A_var , B_var
        from dual;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN others THEN
        update TABLE_NAME set ?????? = null where id = u.id;
    END;
  END LOOP;

  return -1;
END is_number;
```

the top script I want to replace `??????` to name of column as invalid number that in this example name of column is B 
after excution top script,content of table is:

```
ID    A        B
---    ---    ----
 1   123      
 2   587      364
```

Answer (score 0):

What if number conversion errors will be in both columns?

Try this:

```
create or replace function is_number return number is
    a_var number(15);
    b_var number(15);
    function custom_to_number(v varchar2) return number is
        result number;
    begin
        result:=to_number(v);
        return result;
        exception when others then
            if(sqlcode = -6502) then 
                return null;
            end if;
            raise;
    end;
begin
    for u in (select id 
                    ,a
                    ,b
              from table_name)
    loop
        a_var:=custom_to_number(u.a);
        b_var:=custom_to_number(u.b);
        if((u.a is not null and a_var is null) or (u.b is not null and b_var is null)) then
            update table_name
            set a = case when a_var is null then null else a end
               ,b = case when b_var is null then null else b end
            where id = u.id;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return -1;
end is_number;
```

Comment: this is simple salution but if you have 100 column,for any of that must declare try catch then the code will be large

Comment: i want set null for column as invalid data<br/>dont need switch case

Comment: Conversion with exception handling implemented only once in the nested function 'custom_to_number'.

Comment: There is no way to get wrong column from update statement. You can try to use dynamic SQL (dbms_sql) to check every column and generate update script on fly.

Answer (score 0):

If your Intend is to replace the columns which contains alphanuneric data to NULL in the table, then you could use a Trigger to acheive this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_Name BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF 
A_var, B_var ON TABLE_NAME 
 FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN

      IF NOT((regexp_like (:NEW.A_var,'^[[:digit:]]+$'))) THEN
       :NEW.A_var := NULL;
      END IF;

      IF NOT((regexp_like (:NEW.B_var,'^[[:digit:]]+$'))) THEN
       :NEW.B_var := NULL;
      END IF;

    INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(A_var, B_var) Values(:NEW.A_var, :NEW.B_var);

 END;
```